# Limit the number of elements in each row of matrix using Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, replace

I have following numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

and a numpy vector:

```
vector = np.array([1,2])
```

where each element in the vector represents for each row of the matrix, the number of elements I want to retain. I would like to replace all other elements in the matrix with 0.

The final matrix should look like:

```
matrix_output = np.array([[1,0,0],[4,5,0]])
```

What is the quickest way ?

Answer (score 2):

Could do something simple like this:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
vector = np.array([1,2])

for row, index in enumerate(vector):
    matrix[row, index:] = 0

print(matrix)
```

```
[[1 0 0]
 [4 5 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mask = vector[:,None]<=np.arange(3)
matrix[mask] = 0
```